# Restructuring the shape of an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array with shape (64,64) in Python and I want to repeat these elements (three times) in the way that I could have an array with the shape (64,64,3). Any idea?

Comment: you want to make 3 copies of a 2d array and put those in an array? take a look at `copy.deepcopy`

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite: no. The op wants to create an extra dimension, and thus repeat an element at `i,j` in the original array to `i,j,0`, `i,j,1`, and `i,j2` in the new array.

Comment: that is the same thing @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite: not per se. You can make three copies at the first dimension, such that `i,j` of the old matrix maps to `0,i,j`, `1,i,j` and `2,i,j` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the most simplest way to accomplish this here is by using [**`numpy.dstack`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html):

```
import numpy as np

b = np.dstack((a, a, a))
```

where `a` was the original array (shape 64×64), and `b` is the new array (shape 64×64×3).

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thank you very much.